# In Sql (postgres) how to have two aggregate columns at the same time

Tags: sql, postgresql, reporting

I have a table in Postgres:

```
----------------------------------------------
| id | product| price| chain| location| date |           
----------------------------------------------
```

I need to show this as:

September 2018 (per month)

```
         |  sum for the month |  sum for the year so far 
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
location  |          100       |      200
product1  |           1        |        2
product2  |           99       |      198
-----------------------------------------------------------------
Total     |          100       |      200
=================================================================

enter code here
enter code here
```

I can get to "sum of the month" by using group by clauses pretty easily.
But I am stumped as to how to display the second column.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Use a case expression to do conditional aggregation.

Comment: How does *location* line item differ from *Total*? Also, please add data example in your blank posted Postgres table.

Comment: You're going to have to union sub-queries together first (grouping by location in one,product in one), then work out the rolling/cumulative sums.  This is much better left to a presentation tool, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

You want a cumulative sum, something like this:

```
select date_trunc('month', date) as yyyymm, sum(price),
       sum(sum(price)) over (partition by extract(year from date) order by min(date)) as ytd
from location
group by grouping sets ( (yyyymm), () );
```